# Deserializing json with a large amount of properties into java class via Jackson annotation

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

So I am currently using Jackson to deserialize JSON into java objects. Everything works well but I also have some fields such as:

For this kind of JSON file:

```
{
    "uid": 7,
    "asset": 123,
    "currency1_balance": 0,
    "currency2_balance": 0,

    ... ...

    "currencyN_balance": 0,
}
```

we can deserialize it via the java class below:

```
@Test
public void testBalanceJSON() throws IOException {
    // Read in the JSON from the example resources
    InputStream is = BalanceTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/example-balance-data.json");
    //Use Jackson to parse it
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Balance balance = mapper.readValue(is, Balance.class);
}

... ...

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Balance {
    private final BigDecimal uid;
    private final BigDecimal asset;
    private final BigDecimal currency1Balance;
    private final BigDecimal currency2Balance;
    // ... ...
    private final BigDecimal currencyNBalance;

    @JsonCreator
    public Balance(@JsonProperty("uid") BigDecimal uid, @JsonProperty("asset") BigDecimal asset,
                 @JsonProperty("currency1_balance") BigDecimal currency1Balance,
                 @JsonProperty("currency2_balance") BigDecimal currency2Balance,
                 // ... ...
                 @JsonProperty("currencyN_balance") BigDecimal currencyNBalance) {
                    this.uid = uid;
                    this.asset = asset;
                    this.currency1Balance = currency1Balance;
                    this.currency2Balance = currency2Balance;
                    // ... ...
                    this.currencyNBalance = currencyNBalance;
                }
}
```

In above case, I have to write lots of code to deal with the mapping between "currencyN_balance" and "currencyNBalance". Once a currency is added/removed, I'll have to modify the code accordingly, which is quite inflexible. 
Then I found the following way to customize the deserialization process.

```
  @JsonCreator
  public static Balance Create(Map<String, Object> jsonMap) {
     //Resovle the map
     BigDecimal uid = new BigDecimal(jsonMap.get("uid").toString());
     BigDecimal asset = new BigDecimal(jsonMap.get("asset").toString());
     for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : jsonMap.entrySet()){
         if (entry.getKey().startsWith("currency")) {
            //Do something...
         }
     }
     //Then construct the Balance instance and return
  }
```

By using the above method, I can get rid of the boring and error-prone mapping. But I can't leverage the annotation to deal with some parameters' deserialization(e.g. uid, asset).

Is there any ways combining the strengths of both techniques above?
(using annotation with parameter such as uid, asset while being able to customize the currency mapping)

Thanks.

Comment: Why not `BigDecimal[] currencyBalances;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a JSON abomination. That currency_[1..n]_balance should be in an array... as it's an array but encoded in a crappy way.

Anyway, it's not your fault (I hope). For this you can use the Jackson @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter annotations (if you want to serialise and deserialise this class, otherwise you can use only one of them).

For example

```
@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, String value) {
  //do funky transformation/assigment
}
```

Jackson will call that method with any property that it cannot map. So you might need to add some logic to ignore properties that you are not interested.